# Colorful text in the same line in TRichEdit

Tags: delphi, fonts, richedit

How to write text in the same line but with different color? (I use richedit).

```
procedure TForm1.btnEClick(sender: TObject);
begin

  m0.SelAttributes.Color := clBlue;
  m0.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
  m0.lines.add('This is blue and it is bold');
  m0.SelAttributes.Color := clGreen;
  m0.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
  m0.lines.add ('This is Green and it is bold');
  m0.lines.add('');
  m0.lines.add('But how to write text in the same line with different color?');
  // i want to have both blue and green in the same line 
end;
```

Best Wishes,
Bee

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just change `SelAttributes` and use `SelText` instead of `Lines.Add`:

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.Clear;
  RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clBlue;
  RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
  RichEdit1.SelText := 'This is bold blue text.';
  RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clRed;
  RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := [fsItalic];
  RichEdit1.SelText := #32'This is italic red text';
end;
```

This produces

[image: Sample output from code above]

Answer (score 2):

if you are using themes... answer above won't work..
you cannot see any colors...
till you remove seFont from styles..

```
RichEdit1.styleElements:=richedit1.styleElements-[seFont];
```

eg.

```
....
amsg:='Hola';

RichEdit1.SelStart := RichEdit1.GetTextLen();
RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := acolor;
RichEdit1.Lines.Add(amsg + sLineBreak);
RichEdit1.SelLength := Length(amsg + sLineBreak);
```

Comment: Small nitpick: you should change `Length(RichEdit1.Lines.Text)` to `RichEdit1.GetTextLen()`, no need to waste memory retrieving the actual `Text` as a `string` just to get its length, when the `TRichEdit` already knows that info internally.

Answer (score 1):

For the last piece of text in the line, include a carriage return to finish off the line.

```
RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clGreen;
RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := [];
RichEdit1.SelText := 'This is the last piece of text on the line.' + #13;
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. (Ken White probably did answer the intended question.)

Comment: Yes. Ken's answer is correct. I should have added my answer as a comment as it is more a (hopefully) helpful tip rather than an answer. (I don't have enough reputation points to add comments.)

Comment: OK, fair enough! :)